# Rewriting A Text File's Content In An Electron App

Tags: javascript, file, electron, ipc, desktop-application

I want to create a text editor, and so far I was able to add file saving and file opening functionality. I want the text content of the opened file changed according to the textarea in my code, so basically I open a file using Command or Windows + O, and I want to change the content of the file automatically when I make a change on textarea. I have tried solutions with trying to use fs module with preload and index js, but I eventually gave up as I get stuck. Also I couldn't find a way that solves the problem with just changes made on renderer.js

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Chelly</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="file-selector">
      <h2>hello :)</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="text-editor">
      <textarea name="main-textarea" id="main-textarea"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="renderer.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Renderer.js:

```
const textarea = document.getElementById("main-textarea");

document.addEventListener("keydown", async function(event) {
    if (event.key === "s" && (event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey)) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const link = document.createElement("a");
        const textareaContent = textarea.value;
        const file = new Blob([textareaContent], { type: 'text/plain' });
        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        link.download = "saved.txt";
        link.click();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
    }

    if (event.key === "o" && (event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey)) {
        const inputElement = document.createElement("input");
        inputElement.type = "file";
        inputElement.accept = ".txt";
        inputElement.click();

        inputElement.addEventListener("change", () => {
            const file = inputElement.files[0];

            if (file) {
                const reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = (e) => {
                    const fileContent = e.target.result;
                    textarea.value = fileContent;
                }

                reader.readAsText(file);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Index.js:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')
const path = require('node:path')

function createWindow () {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow()
    }
  })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})
```

Preload is empty. I have put the code that does saving and opening file tasks successfully here.

Comment: Try to use `fs` again

Comment: There is no way to use fs module in the renderer process right? I need to mess with index js.

Comment: You can use [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) and a [preload](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload) file.